# Pulling strings with variable length from freetext

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
create table #Test (comments varchar(1000))

 insert into #Test values ('Nominal linking: NOMINAL_ID 9 has been established to be the same person as NOMINAL_ID 1 and the nominals have been linked.')
insert into #Test values ('Nominal linking: NOMINAL_ID 12 has been established to be the same person as NOMINAL_ID 641 and the nominals have been linked.')
insert into #Test values ('Nominal linking: NOMINAL_ID 123 has been established to be the same person as NOMINAL_ID 2019 and the nominals have been linked.')
insert into #Test values ('Nominal linking: NOMINAL_ID 1234 has been established to be the same person as NOMINAL_ID 22222 and the nominals have been linked.')
insert into #Test values ('Nominal linking: NOMINAL_ID 12345 has been established to be the same person as NOMINAL_ID 22 and the nominals have been linked.')
```

I am trying to return the following in an SQL query and do not believe that it can be done:

```
MasterID  ChildID   
9         1
12        641
123       2019
1234      22222
12345     22
```

I realise the design of this table is very poor.  It is an externally developed system.

Comment: You should be able to do it with PatIndex and SubString.

Answer (score 2):

**Function to Extract Numbers**

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_Numbers
( @String NVARCHAR(1000)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS 
BEGIN
 declare @RtnVal nvarchar(50) =''; 

    select @RtnVal = @RtnVal + x.thenum 
    from 
    ( 
        select substring(@String, number, 1) as thenum, number 
        from master..spt_values 
        where substring(@String, number, 1) like '[0-9]' and type='P'
    ) x 
    order by x.number 

   RETURN @RtnVal;
END
```

**Query**

```
SELECT dbo.get_Numbers(LEFT(comments , LEN(comments)/2))  AS Master_ID
     , dbo.get_Numbers(RIGHT(comments , LEN(comments)/2)) AS Child_ID
FROM #Test
```

**Result**

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╗
║ Master_ID ║ Child_ID ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╣
║         9 ║        1 ║
║        12 ║      641 ║
║       123 ║     2019 ║
║      1234 ║    22222 ║
║     12345 ║       22 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: +1 It should be noted however that if one number is quite small and the other consists of many digits that the logic of the select would be incorrect.

Comment: @Ghost, could you give an example?

Comment: Nominal linking: NOMINAL_ID 1 has been established to be the same person as NOMINAL_ID 222222222222222222222222222222222222222220000000000000000000000000222222222222 and the nominals have been linked.

Comment: It is not likely, but that is not a universal solution in the answer. I upvoted the answer, but this edge case does exist.

Comment: @Ghost, thanks for that.  It is an integer column so I believe your scenario does not exist? +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this as the basis of a table valued function. This version is not dependent on one value being located in one half of a string and the other in the other half of a string.

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(1000)='No 9333 ha_ID 112242'
DECLARE @FirstNumber BIGINT=NULL
DECLARE @SecondNumber BIGINT=NULL

DECLARE @Counter SMALLINT=0
DECLARE @CurrentNum VARCHAR(20);

SET @CurrentNum=''
WHILE @Counter<=LEN(@String)+1
BEGIN
    print SUBSTRING(@String,@Counter,1)
    IF(@Counter=LEN(@String)+1 AND LEN(@CurrentNum)>0)
        BEGIN
            IF @FirstNumber IS NULL SET @FirstNumber=CONVERT(BIGINT,@CurrentNum)
            IF @FirstNumber IS NOT NULL SET @SecondNumber=CONVERT(BIGINT,@CurrentNum)
            SET @CurrentNum=''
        END
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@String,@Counter,1) like '[0-9]'
        BEGIN
            SET @CurrentNum=@CurrentNum+SUBSTRING(@String,@Counter,1)
        END
    ELSE IF LEN(@CurrentNum)>0
        BEGIN
            IF @FirstNumber IS NULL SET @FirstNumber=CONVERT(BIGINT,@CurrentNum)
            IF @FirstNumber IS NOT NULL SET @SecondNumber=CONVERT(BIGINT,@CurrentNum)
            SET @CurrentNum=''
        END

    SET @Counter=@Counter+1
END

select @FirstNumber [First Number],@SecondNumber [Second Number]
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute force using charindex and other string functions:

select  SUBSTRING(comments,29, CHARINDEX('has been' ,comments)- 29) 
as master_id, 
left(substring(SUBSTRING(comments,charindex('as nominal_id ',comments)+14,CHARINDEX(' and the nominals have been linked.',comments)),1,6),CHARINDEX(' ',substring(SUBSTRING(comments,charindex('as nominal_id ',comments)+14,CHARINDEX(' and the nominals have been linked.',comments)),1,6))) as child_id from #test

Comment: I tried m. ali's much, much more elegant solution on 28000 rows of data and it took 2:06 (two minutes and six seconds) and my solution took 1 second.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for an sql statement really. I will test it tomorrow and get back to you.